# NetSuite formula search for data between first/last day of future month

Tags: sql, netsuite

I'm trying to create a NetSuite saved search using SQL formulas.  In my criteria I need a formula that returns true if the {expectedclosedate} is within the start and end of the month 3 months from now.  Netsuite uses Oracle SQL.  This is where I'm at currently:

```
CASE WHEN (TRUNC((ADD_MONTHS({today}, 3)),'MM')
<= {expectedclosedate} <=
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS({today}, 3))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Anyone have any advice or an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this does the job.

```
{expectedclosedate},'YYYYMM') = to_char(ADD_MONTHS({today},3), 'YYYYMM')) 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```